# Which contract does Opensea uses for polygon mumbai?

Tags: nft, polygon, opensea

I've been testing buying NFT on Opensea.
I've bought nft on rinkeby, which will trigger AtomicMatch of the underlying wyvern exchange contract.

However, after I've done the same thing for Opensea mumbai, I've noticed that it has called a function which signature is `0xbbbfa60c`

ref: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xf370ff900654a14f009a006f36feea5552aca2f7239e0c926ef9985ee088b9a8

And I search for this function signature and found that it is matchOrders (https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0xbbbfa60c)

So does opensea use different exchange contract for ethereum and polygon or am I missing something?

Appreciate any helps or suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0):

OpenSea uses different order matching for ethereum and polygon. On Ethereum, Wyvern is used, but on Polygon, 0x v3 is used.